# jquery multiple select shows and hide google map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a filterfunction for google maps markers first it worked perfectly but than I wanted to have an multiple select box and than the function was not working anymore because the output is an Array i think.

Here is an working example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sylvanR/vmt1eLag/3/)

This is the filterMarker function:

```
filterMarkers = function (category) {
  var selectedValue = $(".select-multiple").val();
  console.log($(".select-multiple").val(), category);

  for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
    marker = gmarkers1[i];
    // If is same category or category not picked
    if (marker.category == selectedValue || category.length === 0) {
     // console.log('mcat', marker.category, 'cat', category);
          marker.setVisible(true);
    }
    // Categories don't match 
    else {
       marker.setVisible(false);
    }
 }
}
```

Thereby I tried this to do a `forEach` loop trough selected values and than check if they match with category of the marker:

```
var foo = [];
$('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected){
   foo[i] = $(selected).val();
   var result = JSON.stringify(foo[i]);

   console.log(result);

   for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
     marker = gmarkers1[i];
   // If is same category or category not picked
   if (marker.category == result || result.length === 0) {
    // console.log('mcat', marker.category, 'cat', category);
     marker.setVisible(true);
   }
  }
 });
```

What am I doing wrong in my filterMarkers `function` could someone help me out on this one?!

Comment: Not sure why you got marked down - seems well explained and a reasonable description of the issue. Your fiddle was fine.

Comment: Could you upvote it

Comment: Pleased to have helped. +1 upvote on your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. You have to detect if there are any filters selected and clear or show all pins, then show the selected pins in the loop.

```
filterMarkers = function(category) {

  // New - clear all markers or show all. If needed the selected markers will be made visible in following step.
  if ($('.select-multiple :selected').length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
      gmarkers1[i].setVisible(false);
    }
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
      gmarkers1[i].setVisible(true);
    }
  }

  $('.select-multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {

    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
      marker = gmarkers1[i];
      // If is same category or category not picked
      if (marker.category == $(selected).val() ) {
        // console.log('mcat', marker.category, 'cat', category);
        marker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Note - could not get a snippet running here because I could not get the google map link to work. However, the OP's fiddle works and if you paste the above function over his function of same name then it runs well. Trust me I tried hard with the snippet but could not get it to play.