# (HTML5/JS) Collect data from <select><option> tag and perform a task - Open up an embedded Google map

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm currently learning HTML5/CSS/JS and I need some help with the below:

I'm trying to create a document/page, where the user would have a drop-down selection menu
and by selecting any of the given options, let's say supermarkets, an embedded google map
would pop on the screen, showing the locations/pins of the supermarkets.
If the user was to select another option, let's say gas stations, a different map would pop up.

I know how to create the map with the locations,
however, I don't know how to link my  tag with them.
Bear in mind that I want to stay on the same document/page, when the option is selected
and NOT get transferred to a google maps page.

Could you assist?

Thanks,
Val.

Comment: Do you want it to pop-up (something like a modal, or a floating / draggable window), or to constantly occupy a position on the screen? Also, [this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048760/) (both the question and the answer), when it comes to connecting the dropdown / select and the markers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery

```
$("#yourselectboxid").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() === "optionValue") {
    $("#googleH").dialog();
  }
});
```

Or you can use bootstrap model and open it using

```
$("googleModal").modal("show");
```